# Unable to Return output from function

Tags: arrays, powershell, netapp

```
function Get-NaLUNbyMap {
<#
.DESCRIPTION
Gets Lun Information for a particular initiatorgroup name & lunid
.EXAMPLE
Get-Inventory -computername server-r2
.EXAMPLE
Import-Module NaLUNbyMap
Get-NaLUNbyMap -igroup "IA" -lunid 1
#>
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
[string[]]$igroup,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
[string[]]$lunid
)
Process 
{ 

$info = (Get-NaLun |Select @{Name="LUN";Expression={$_.path}},@{Name="Size";Expression={[math]::Round([decimal]$_.size/1gb,0)}},@{Name="OnlineStatus";Expression={$_.online}},@{Name="Group";Expression={([string]::Join(",",(Get-NaLun $_.path | get-nalunmap | select -ExpandProperty initiatorgroupname)))}},@{Name="LunID";Expression={Get-NaLun $_.path | get-nalunmap | select -ExpandProperty lunid}} | ?{$_.group -eq $igroup -and $_.lunid -eq $lunid})
return $info
}
}
```

Hi Im unable to return output from this function, can some one please help me out!

Comment: @JasonMArcher can you please help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104316/unable-to-extract-virtualnetwork-name-using-scvmm-powershell-modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is some ugly code.  :(

Here is a cleaned up version.  I think I found your problem.  Your parameters are arrays, when they should be single values based on how you are using them.

```
function Get-NaLUNbyMap {
    <#
    .DESCRIPTION
    Gets Lun Information for a particular initiatorgroup name & lunid
    .EXAMPLE
    Get-Inventory -computername server-r2
    .EXAMPLE
    Import-Module NaLUNbyMap
    Get-NaLUNbyMap -igroup "IA" -lunid 1
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeline = $True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True)]
        [string]$igroup
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeline = $True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True)]
        [string]$lunid
    )

    process { 
        $Luns = foreach ($Lun in Get-NaLun) {
            $LunMap = Get-NaLunMap $_.Path

            New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                "LUN"= $_.Path
                "Size" = [Math]::Round([Decimal]$_.Size / 1gb, 0)
                "OnlineStatus" = $_.Online
                "Group" = $LunMap | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InitiatorGroupName
                "LunId" = $LunMap | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LunId
            }
        }
        $Luns | Where-Object {$_.Group -eq $igroup -and $_.LunId -eq $lunid}
    }
}
```