# Extracting ClusterName RegularExpressions

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a regular expression which will give the computername, cluster name & OSinfo

Get-QADComputer | ? {$*.osname -match "2008" -and $*.computername -match "hv"} | 
`Select @{Name="ComputerName";Expression={$_.computername.replace("$","")}}`
,@{Name="ClusterName";Expression={$*.computername.replace("$","");$*.computername.replace("n[0-9][0-9]","")}},@{Name="OperatingSystem";Expression={$_.osname}}

Now the problem im facing is in extracting the clustername,
for example if output of computer name is ADFCGS1N01$, i wanted the cluster name to look like ADFCGSN1, i wanted to remove all the characters after N to get cluster name,

Can some one please help me with the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this gives you the correct value?

```
Get-QADComputer -OSName *2008* -Name *hv* | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Per your comment, remove the N+2 digits from the end of name, including the dollar (if exists):

```
Get-QADComputer -OSName *2008* -Name *hv* | Foreach-Object {$_.Name -replace 'N\d{2}\$?$'}
```

Comment: PS C:\Users\vinith> Get-QADComputer LYGTFBL1N02$ | Select -ExpandProperty Name
LYGTFBL1N02

Hi SHay what i wanted is the output to be LYGTFBL1, there should be no characters after "N"

Comment: All computers in the command I posted have 02$ at the end of the name?

Comment: Hi Shay, what i wanted is that all the computernames which have a N[0-9][0-9] should be replaced by null, for example if server name is LHYTFC1N01, the output should be LHYTFC1

Comment: PS C:\Users\supervinith> Get-QADComputer  -Name LHPHT2N01 | Foreach-Object {$_.Name -replace '\d{2}$'}
LHPHT2N

Hi shay i wanted also the "N" to go away, i wanted my output to be LHPHT2

Comment: Check the thread again, the pattern you need to use is 'N\d{2}\$?$'

Comment: Hi @Shay Levy can you please help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181031/remove-favourite-targets-disconnect-iscsi-targets-using-iscsicli-exe-powersh