# Remove Favourite Targets & Disconnect iscsi targets using iscsicli.exe & powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, iscsi

Hi all i wanted to Remove Favourite Targets & Disconnect iscsi targets using iscsicli.exe & powershell for microsoft iscsi initiator, can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Did you find out the solution to remove Favorite targets through PowerShell ? I am looking for same solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and posed an iSCSI module I created for just this purpose: http://poshcode.org/3066

Docs are in process, but if you understand how to use iscsicli you should have no problems using this iSCSI module.

Comment: Hi @beefarino your powershel module looks awesome, i wanted to remove Favourite Targets & Disconnect iscsi targets all automatically, like if i call a function it should remove all favourite targets one by one automatically without using any parameters & also dicsonnect the iscsi targets.

Comment: The module probably contains the components to create such a function - I know the list targets and remove capability is there.  with some experimenting you can probably find a way to use the module to list the favorite targets too.